# Zombie Plague rules for a one-shot

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, zombies

I'm planning a one-shot set in a zombie apocalypse (original, I know), and I'd like there to be an escalating infection inflicted on the players.

---

**Ravenous Plague**

Whenever an infected character hits a player, they must make a DC5 Constitution Save. On a fail, they have contracted the infection - gain 1 stack of Festering Wound.

**Festering Wound**

The wound caused by the undead refuses to heal - you can staunch the bleeding temporarily, but it opens again at the slightest touch. You feel a pulsing ache around the site of the wound.

Once every 5 minutes, take a Constitution Save, DC5 + the number of stacks of Festering Wound you already have. On a fail, gain another stack of Festering Wound.

On reaching 5 stacks of Festering Wound, the player is affected by Unyielding Hunger.

On reaching 15 stacks of Festering Wound, the player is affected by Ravenous Plague.

**Unyielding Hunger**

You are aware of a gnawing hunger in the pit of your stomach, which food only temporarily abates. The skin around your wound starts turning a sickly gray-green.

When taking a Festering Wound Constitution Save, you may add +5 to the result if you have eaten within the last 10 minutes.

**Ravenous Plague**

The hunger is now becoming all-consuming, overriding your senses at times.

You no longer need to take Festering Wound Constitution Saves.

At the start of each turn of combat, take a DC5 Constitution Save. On a fail, you must spend your turn moving towards the closest non-infected character and make an unarmed attack against them if possible. If they take damage from you, they must take a DC5 Constitution Save or gain a stack of Festering Wound.

---

The players can cure themselves of the Plague by consuming a potion given to them by an NPC, so it's not a one-way street.

The DM will keep track of the plague stacks on each player, and will reveal each new stage of the infection as required.

The idea behind the plague is that it's not guaranteed that they get infected, but then when they do catch it it ramps up in intensity over time.

The party will be made up of 5 level 3 players, including 2 paladins, a barbarian, a wizard and a fighter. I'm not sure if these rules I've come up with are too harsh or lenient.

I'm also not sure what to do with the paladins, as they're supposed to be immune to disease - my first thought was to give them a +2 advantage on all Constitution Saves for this mechanic. And then there's Lay On Hands - I dont really want them to be able to trivialise the plague by curing it straight away.

Any thoughts you have would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to our stack, Sok! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: Unlike a traditional forum, we are more of a Q&A site and don't delve into idea generation. We do [homebrew reviews](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/), but please take a look at the meta for suggestions on how to write a good review question. The first big step is in providing a clear homebrew for us to review, if you're still in the homebrew generation phase, then that's too early for us. But you can absolutely hop into our very own [chat] to get more feedback and help develop it.

Comment: *"Once every 5 minutes, take a Constitution Save"* is it real time or game time?

Comment: Echoing NautArch: I think there are stackable elements to this question but, as of right now, it's way too open ended to allow for a concise answer. You might try focusing on specific balance issues in the context of your party's characters.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sorcerers, Barbarians, and Fighters are probably immune to the plague already.

DC 5 is really low. Sorcerers, Barbarians, and Fighters have proficiency in constitution saving throws, so a constitution of at least 14 means they are entirely immune to the disease.

For others, having a constitution modifier over 0 still makes it hard to get infected. Even at +1, the chances of getting infected on a hit are only 15%, so the average number of hits taken before getting infected is 6 or 7 (1/.15=6.666).

#### It will either take longer than the game to reach Unyielding Hunger, or the players will get super infected all at once.

Here is a table of the expected number of hits (or timed saves) required to reach 5 stacks based on CON save bonus:

| CON Sav | Avg. rolls till Unyielding Hunger |
| --- | --- |
| +0 | 17.7 |
| +1 | 21.9 |
| +2 | 29 |
| +3 | 45.7 |
| +4 | Immune |

With a meager +1 to Constitution Saves, the expected hits till reaching Unyielding Hunger is 21.9. This is already probably longer than your session will last without extended periods of making multiple timed saves. If the party walks for an hour, are you going to say, "okay, everyone needs to make 12 saving throws"? This is the only way you are going to reach higher levels, and it becomes increasingly likely that they players will contract several stacks all at once.

Comment: You're not wrong about this current issue, but the state of the homebrew also looks way too early for a response here.